# How to activate a spinner directive from a service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

### How does one use an AngularJS directive inside an AngularJS service?

In my AngularJS 1.5 application, I have a directive that displays a spinner in the center of the view. I would like to be able to activate this spinner by way of a service.

So for example, the service could be injected into a controller, and whenever called, it would trigger the spinner to be displayed on the screen.

How can I inject this directive into the service?

Presently, everywhere I look, iI can only find instructions on how to inject services into directives, but not the other way around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is to use the [$rootScope/$scope event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) bus:

```
 app.service("dataService", function($rootScope, $http) {
     this.get = function() {
         $rootScope.$broadcast("dataService.Start");
         return $http.get(url).finally(function() {
             $rootScope.$broadcast("dataService.Done");
         });
     };
 })
```

In the directive:

```
 app.directive("spinner", function() {
     return {
         link: postLink,
     };
     function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
         scope.$on("dataService.Start", function (event) {
             elem[0].startSpinner();
         });
         scope.$on("dataService.Done", function (event) {
             elem[0].stopSpinner();
         });
     }
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Event Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation)

Comment: brilliant! Thank you very much George!

Answer (score 0):

You can install [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner)
then include files in your index.html
and add dependencie to your app :

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['angularSpinner']);
```

then you can use custom directive to intercept all http requests without add start before each http call and stop after (less code)

```
app.directive('usSpinner', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
      $rootScope.spinnerActive = false;
      scope.isLoading = function () {
        return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
      };

      scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function (loading) {
        $rootScope.spinnerActive = loading;
        if (loading) {
          elm.removeClass('ng-hide');
        } else {
          elm.addClass('ng-hide');
        }
      });
    }
  };

}
```

Then in your html add this to body :

```
<span us-spinner></span>
```